# Collapse Hovering Dropdown Menu After Clicking Option

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to collapse a hovering dropdown menu after clicking an option and show the dropdown again once the user "hovers" over it. I've tried everything and nothing seems to work. Right now, everytime when the user clicks an option, the dropdown menu options don't disappear. I've tried to "hide" the dropdown menu after clicking it and then forcing the dropdown menu to show when a user hovers over it but to of no avail.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dropdown ul li').on('click', function() {


    //$(".dropdown ul li").hide();
    $(this).toggleClass('data-value');
    var label = $(this).parent().parent().children('label');
    label.attr('data-value', $(this).attr('data-value'));
    label.html($(this).html());
    $(this).children().slideUp();
    $(this).parent().children('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    // When you hover, call   $(".dropdown ul li").show();

  });


});
```

```css
CSS : .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 275px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown label {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background: #EA8C02;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown ul li {
  padding: 0px 16px;
  background: #DDD;
  color: #343838;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: height 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.dropdown ul li:hover,
.dropdown ul li.selected {
  background: #00B4CC;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown:hover ul li {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <label data-value="">Discount Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li data-value="1">$5.00</li>
      <li data-value="2">10.00</li>
      <li data-value="3">$15.00</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `function` to this

```
 $(function () {
        $('.dropdown ul li').on('click', function () {
            $('.dropdown ul li').css({padding: '0px', height: '0px'});
        });

        // Reset style

        $('.dropdown ul').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $('.dropdown ul li').removeAttr("style");
        });
    });
```

See working snippet below. Cheers!

```js
   
   $(function () {
        $('.dropdown ul li').on('click', function () {
            $('.dropdown ul li').css({padding: '0px', height: '0px'});
        });
        
        // Reset style
        
        $('.dropdown ul').on('mouseleave', function () {
            $('.dropdown ul li').removeAttr("style");
        });
    });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 275px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dropdown label {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  background: #EA8C02;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.dropdown ul li {
  padding: 0px 16px;
  background: #DDD;
  color: #343838;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: height 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.dropdown ul li:hover,
.dropdown ul li.selected {
  background: #00B4CC;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown:hover ul li {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="dropdown">
    <label data-value="">Discount Amount</label>
    <ul>
      <li data-value="1">$5.00</li>
      <li data-value="2">10.00</li>
      <li data-value="3">$15.00</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: NICE! THanks! that is super helpful appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you please accept my answer as the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the answer is

```js
function start(){
var x =document.getElementByTagName("p");
x.style.color="red";
}
```

```css
a:active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">hello world im active </a>
<p onclick="start();">hello im onclick </P>
```

Comment: Does that collapse the dropdown menu after click?